# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n!x^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I've got difficulties finding the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n!x^{n^2}$. I've already tried presenting it as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n x^n$, where $b_n = (\sqrt{n})!$ if $n$ is a square and $b_n=0$ otherwise. I wanted to use the Cauchy–Hadamard formula and ended up with something like this: $$\frac{1}{R}=\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{\lvert b_n \rvert} = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{(\sqrt{n})!}$$ And I'm not sure if it's correct. Even if it was, I wouldn't know how to calculate this limit.

Comment: For the original series, simply use the ratio test. The ratio test is usually good when factorials are present because there is so much cancellation when dividing two consecutive factorials.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio test gives

$$L=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$$

$$=x.\lim_{n\to+\infty}(n+1)e^{2n\ln(|x|)}$$

If $ |x|<1 $, $ L=0 $ it converges.

if $ |x|>1 $ , $L=+\infty$, it diverges.

thus the radius is $ R=1$.